# Loosely couple a modal dialog - is this possible?

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I have a winforms custom UI control library which contains a control for displaying modal dialogs Picture-in-Picture.

This custom control receives as a parameter a pointer to the control which has initiated it's display.  So they are tied together.  This allows the control to be modally displayed over the window which launched it.

```
    Dim f As New PiPCustomDialog       'this form wraps another form PictureInPicture style  
    f.FormToLoad = New PrintOptions()  'this is the form the user will interact with  
    f.Owner = Me                       'used to determine the size of PiPCustomDialog   
    Dim dr As DialogResult = f.ShowDialog(Me) 'shows PiPCustonDialog coating, f's OnLoad event initiates display of FormToLoad centered within.
```

The fact that this control requires f.Owner to be set is what is stinky.  User32.dll has a function GetActiveWindow() which would maybe allow the control to be more self-sufficient.

Anyone out there who would like to teach this old dog a new trick?  I want to learn a better way.

Comment: I don't get it.  Does it look better if you just delete the f.Owner assignment?  It isn't needed, passing Me to ShowDialog() does the same thing.  Or is this actually a control instead of a form?  What's "f"?

Comment: Ok, you're right that was unclear.  f is an instance of the custom control.  I'll add more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use this solution for now:

- Remove any validation that requires
  owner to be set before showing the
  form modally.
- if owner isn't set inside the class that is transparent cover
  (first form) -    do a system call into
  GetActiveWindow to get owner so the size of the window can be set.